# How to achieve successful Peltier cooling

Tags: heat-transfer, cooling

I'm using a TEC12706 Peltier module for making a cooling setup. The hot side rejects heat to a Cooler Master Hyper 410R cooler and the cold side fin gets cold enough to form water condensate on itself.
I then tried to connect a small 12V CPU fan to the cold fin and measured the temperature of the air coming from the fan, the fan basically throws air onto the cooled fin and the air then escapes from the sides, but I'm only able to achieve a temperature drop of 0.2C in the air. I think it may be due to the less contact time of air with the fin, how can I increase the contact time of air with the cool surface or is there something else going on?
[A similar setUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVGp0.png)!

Comment: reduce the speed of the air, aka increase the time the air is in contact with the fins.

Comment: also carefully enclose the fan and fin arrangement in a close-fitting shroud to eliminate losses.